# how to Play wmv and flv files in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video

i want to play video files like wmv and flv in my asp.net mvc application? what is the best solution or plugin to do so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has little to do with ASP.NET MVC and more to do with HTML. You'll find numerous resources online of how to do this in HTML:

- http://www.walkernews.net/2008/08/17/windows-media-player-how-to-embed-wmv-file-in-html-code/
- http://www.walkernews.net/2008/01/11/how-to-embed-flv-flash-in-wordpress-or-html/

That was just from a quick bing search for "embed wmv html" and "embed flv html" respectively. There's nothing in MVC that is specifically designed for handling WMV/FLV. If you need to use data from your controller to build the embed HTML code, you can output it from your Model like you normally would for links or anything else (i.e. <%=Model.VideoUrl %>)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Paul.

I'd like to add that once you are set on the html/script you will be using, you can put it in a custom extension method so in the view it ends something short like:

```
<%: Html.FlashVideo(someFilePath, related values) %>
```